# Jenkins could not start Windows slave

Tags: ssh, jenkins

when I'm trying to start jenkins slave (windows) I get this error:

```
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to pcskala:22105.
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] Authentication successful.
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] The remote users environment is:
Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] SFTP failed. Copying via SCP.
hudson.util.IOException2: Could not copy slave.jar into 'c:\Users\jenkins' on slave
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJarUsingSCP(SSHLauncher.java:1065)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJar(SSHLauncher.java:1024)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$300(SSHLauncher.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:709)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sorry, this connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.ensureConnected(TransportManager.java:587)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.sendMessage(TransportManager.java:660)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.openSessionChannel(ChannelManager.java:572)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Session.<init>(Session.java:42)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.openSession(Connection.java:1129)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.exec(Connection.java:1551)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJarUsingSCP(SSHLauncher.java:1048)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherOutputStream.flush(CipherOutputStream.java:75)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.sendMessage(TransportConnection.java:193)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.sendMessage(TransportConnection.java:107)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.sendMessage(TransportManager.java:677)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.closeChannel(ChannelManager.java:304)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Session.close(Session.java:565)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.exec(Connection.java:1568)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.reportEnvironment(SSHLauncher.java:1071)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:704)
    ... 5 more
[07/07/15 12:54:15] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/07/15 12:54:15] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Windows slave is running SSH and SFTP servers. Keys should be set fine, because I can connect to that machine via `ssh` and copy files via `scp` and `sftp` as well without entering password (from Unix system). I apologize that I don't post any more info, but I do not have direct access to slaves configuration in jenkins.

I don't know if this is important, but `slave.jar` file is located in home folder: `C:\Users\jenkins`.

I have found a thread in jenkins issues, where one had the similar issue and he resolved it with changing permission to /dev/null, but I don't think (just a thought) this would be the reason.
Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Any success with this issue?